# Comment on traduire "une source de" en anglais?

Tags: traduction

Voici une phrase: "Une source de k symboles ayant une distribution P peut être  asymptotiquement encodée avec H(P) bits en moyenne."

I'm wondering who to translate "Une source de".

I would translate it as "a text with k symbols where the frequency of the symbols follow the distribution P could be encoded with H(O) bits in average."

Comment: A source of k symbols?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for translating an expression from French to English and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation isn't wrong – it's good English and it has the correct meaning. However, the usual information-theoretic English translation of *une source* would be *a source*.

This is [Shannon's Source Coding Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem).

I don't know whether, by *de k symboles*, you mean an alphabet of *k* different symbols, or *k* symbols in total. Assuming the second,
I'd translate the whole thing as

> k symbols from a source with probability distribution P can asymptotically be encoded using an average of H(P) bits per symbol.

I don't know why you don't say *bits par symbole* in French, but I can find a statement of the theorem online as

> Théorème (Shannon):
>   Une source ayant une distribution P peut être asymptotiquement encodée avec H(P) bits en moyenne et pas mieux.

so it appears that in French, one doesn't always specify *bits par symbole*.